# Testing CuDNN 7.6.5 Install on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, cuda

I am trying to test my installation of [CuDNN](https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn) 7.6.5 on Ubuntu 18.04. I installed CUDA 10.2 and ran through the tests for that without issue. When I try to run the MNIST example to test my CuDNN install, I get these errors:

`cat: /usr/local/cuda/include/cuda.h: no such file or directory`
`/bin/sh: 1: /usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc: not found`

Running `which nvcc` returns `/usr/local/cuda-10.2/bin/nvcc` and my `cuda.h` file is in `/usr/local/cuda-10.2/include/cuda.h`

This is what `echo $PATH` returns: `/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/cuda-10.2/bin:/usr/local/cuda-10.2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`

I have a feeling it can't find `cuda.h` or `nvcc` because they are in `cuda-10.2` directories and it is searching in `cuda` directories, but I can't figure out how to fix that. I'm pretty new to Ubuntu/CUDA/etc.

Comment: Try running `/sbin/ldconfig -N -v $(sed 's/:/ /' <<< $LD_LIBRARY_PATH)` to test if CuDNN is installed.

Comment: Does the /usr/local/cuda directory even exist?  If not, make it a link to the cuda-10.2 dir.  Fix your PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH getting rid of the cuda-10.2 and the doubling (maybe caused by mods in both .profile and .bashrc).